# Windows API call sequence monitoring

Tags: windows, api

I need to monitor an API call sequence created by a process running on Microsoft Windows, to analyze malware behavior.

I know we can do user mode or kernel mode monitoring. I have tried some tools that can intercept API calls, like Detours, EasyHook, and NTHookEngine, but all of them, in my understanding, utilize the user mode monitoring. This makes it impossible for them to detect malware running in the kernel mode (like rootkits).

If we try to hook API call using Detours or EasyHook we have to define our own hooking function which in this case I don't need to. I just need to know the function that is being called by a monitored process and its parameters.

Is there any way to do it in efficient (few line of codes) and effective (user mode and kernel mode monitor) way?

Comment: As you can see from the edits, I am trying to understand you concern. What do you mean by "*we have to define our own hooking function which in this case I don't need to*" and how does it create a problem for you?

Comment: If user mode monitoring works, why use kernel mode monitoring? What's wrong with the approach? Also, why implement it yourself since there is http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor?

Comment: @techraf I need to hook all win32 api calls which are included in win32.dll. The number of functions is large, more than a thousand. If I use easyhook or detours I need to define my own function for replacing every api function that will be hooked. While all of my own functions will just literally write the name of hooked function and its parameters, I still have to code more than a thousand of that functions.

Comment: @Thomas I need to be able to program it because I am doing a research on analyzing malware based on its api calls sequence

Answer (score 2):

Regarding user-mode hooks, perhaps you can write a generic stub function that

1. Hooks onto all the kernel32 calls.
2. Passes the call to the original API address (you'll have to build an array of all the original API addresses to determine the correct address).
3. Compare the callee's address against the IAT to the original API address.

This call sequencing technique for rootkit detection can clearly detect hooks, but I can't imagine it would work for runtime patching - AKA inline hooks, as they don't build a stack frame.

If you're reluctant to go down this route, you might consider hooking onto the Native API in kernel mode, which has about ~290 functions for Windows 7 SP1. You'll have to disable or bypass PatchGuard on x64 systems though.